# "Pouring from the window" vs "pouring in from the window"

Tags: word-usage, sentence

> Mary woke to the soft light pouring from the window.
>
> Mary woke to the soft light pouring in from the window.

What's the difference? Do they mean exactly the same?

Comment: They are both idiomatic.  I myself wouldn't use the first one—it sounds weird.

Comment: To me "pouring from the window" has an implication of "pouring out from...", so in that sense they're not the same.  But "pouring through the window" might be be better than both, let the context convey they direction.

Comment: "Pouring in through the window" is how I would put it, because that's the combination with 'pouring' that seems most idiomatic to me. "Streaming in through the window" sounds even better.

Comment: http://www.talkenglish.com/how-to-use/Pour confirms pour+in and I think *through the window* is preferable to *from the window* because light comes from the sun not from a window.

Comment: At present, “light pouring” (which I regard as clunky) [occurs about 1/3 as frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=light+pouring%2Clight+streaming&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clight%20pouring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20streaming%3B%2Cc0) as “light streaming”.   I regard “Mary woke to the soft light pouring [in]” (or streaming [in]) as misguided writing; it produces a nice image, but lazily and ambiguously suggests either the light woke Mary or Mary saw the light when she awoke. Use another word or two and rewrite it.

Comment: MariLou - "because light comes from the sun not from a window" nonsensical, you say water comes from a tap (not "the dam"). Also, physically, note that it is in fact coming from the window.  talkenglish - lol you mention that humorously as a reference right?  Also overwhelmingly (in spite of two people here asserting it is not the case) **"LIGHT POURING FROM THE WINDOW"** is utterly commonplace in English, spoken and written. Just google, even, for goodness sake. (I wouldn't tell you what's common in Italian :) )

Comment: BY the way "pouring out of" is yet another commonly-said one.  Pouring from the window, pouring in from outside through the window, pouring through the window, pouring out of the window -- all utterly common and normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pouring from the window* is poetic license.  In my experience, it is not what I hear people say ordinarily (often).

It is used here, I'm guessing, to give the impression that the **source of light is the window** itself (like water comes from a spring), instead of the light coming from outside.

The feeling conveyed may be that the room and its occupants are quite **separated from what is outside** (psychologically or in some other way). It is as if there is nothing beyond the room - even its light from the window is *from the window*, not from outside.

As comments to the question have indicated, a usual expression would be *pouring in from outside* or *pouring in from the window* (*window* as conduit here, or even as surrogate for the outside light source).  Or the same but with *through* instead of *from*.

Comment: To be honest I find this all confusing. (1) "pouring from the window" is commonplace, it's surprising anyone has said otherwise. (just google it) (2) technically it is, certainly, **pouring from the window**.  exactly like water pours from a tap, or blood pores from a cut, or light pours down from the from the opening in the ceiling.  You would rarely say "water is pouring in from the tap" or "through the tap" or the like.

Comment: Ha I'm confused now, too

Comment: @JoeBlow: That's because one often thinks of a water tap as a **source** of water. One doesn't often think of a window as a **source** of light. But of course it is, just as much as a tap is a source of water. That's the point. You can think of either in these two different ways (and of course other ways). It's like a state diagram: for a given node, any input can be seen as an input from a source instead of from an intermediate node. A state diagram can be simplified by collapsing intermediate nodes (abstracting). It's all about **point of view**. *From* here **views the window as a source**.

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm not sure if you;'re agreeing or disagreeing with me. The point is: "'light pouring from the window' is commonplace.  IE: **English speakers often say "Light is pouring from the window."**

Comment: @JoeBlow: I don't know whether they (we) do or do not often say that. My point is that this says something slightly different from *Light is pouring* ***in*** *from the window.* The denotation is the same, but the connotation is slightly different: The point of view wrt the window (and the outside world) changes. In one case, you are not looking beyond the window for the cause/source; your view of the light (what it is, its cause etc.) stops at the window. In the other, you are not only looking beyond the window, you are pretty much ignoring it (not seeing the window itself).

Comment: @JoeBlow: Let me add that no, when people speak they do not make such a distinction, at least not consciously. (They may well make it unconsciously.)  It's about feeling. The context here is literature, and the question, as I see it, is why the author chose the expression that was chosen. I offered one possible reason. I have no idea whether the actual author used this wording for that reason. To me, that is the effect (an effect), and I assume it was intended by the author.

Comment: "I don't know whether they (we) do or do not often say that. " in the answer you wrote: "It is not what one would say ordinarily."

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yes, it is my opinion/experience that they (we) do not ordinarily (often) say that. I do not know for a fact whether my experience reflects the situation generally or everywhere. You are welcome to disagree. The question, and the point, I think, is, as the OP wrote: ***What's the difference? Do they mean exactly the same?*** I tried to address that.

Comment: "I do not know for a fact whether my experience reflects the situation generally or everywhere"   I am, let's say, 85% certain that "pouring from the window" is somewhat more commonplace; both are commonplace. (Just google, even, to see it everywhere.)  Regarding the difference. Yes, I utterly understand the difference you have explained. However I'd suggest they are both used (commonly) as figures of speech, and there is no difference meant when people (randomly) say one or the other. In short the first two sentences of your answer, to me seem wrong. Cheers for now!

Comment: @JoeBlow: OK, I think we've reached a fixed point. The comments clarify that my statement about ordinary usage is based on personal experience, and you've tried to show that general usage differs from my experience. And we are clear that this is a side issue and not the question at hand, which is about the difference.

Comment: @JoeBlow: I edited the answer to clarify this there.

Comment: To clarify, why do you say "Pouring from the window is poetic license."?  Is that because (for you) it's unusual, not what people normally say?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Please read what I've written, including: *The context here is literature, and the question, as I see it, is why the author chose the expression that was chosen.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a new innovation on ESO!  Answering the actual question! :)

"What's the difference? Do they mean exactly the same?"

1) there is absolutely no difference

2) they mean exactly the same thing

Comment: _It was a moonlit night. As I walked to her parents' house, I knew she was home: there was light pouring from her window._ - So, that means the same as _pouring in from her window_? The version without _in_ is simply ambiguous and needs context to indicate whether it flows in or out. I agree that, given a context, both can well be equivalent.

Comment: The italics text is utterly, perfectly, totally, 100% clear. And it's exactly what you normally say. The light was pouring **from** her window. (We're on the street - "Look, Steve must still be awake, light's pouring from every window..."  Totally normal and straightforward.) Imagine the house was full of water (it's like a tank) and there was a hole.  You'd say the water was pouring from the hole.